# What is the difference between GetCommitsAsync and GetCommitsBatchAsync?

Tags: c#, git, tfs, azure-devops

I am using methods from **GitHttpClientBase** class from Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi namespace in [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/) package.

There are 2 similar methods for retrieving commits: **GetCommitsAsync** and **GetCommitsBatchAsync**. Do you know what is the difference? When each of them should be used?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any difference between them. They both retrieve git commits for a project and use the same input parameters and return the same object, you can check this from "Object Browser":
[image]
Or from this link: [getCommits() & getCommitsBatch()](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/versioncontrol/gitrestclient/githttpclient2_1#getCommits)