# TFS Git Commit web page API call to get related WorkItems

Tags: c#, git, api, tfs

I am trying to get a Git Commit related Work Items programmaticaly through the TFS REST API. I haven't found examples online but the tfs web portal seems to get this information by using a 'associatedWorkItems' api call...

When I navigate to my TFS portal for a given Git Commit:

http://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_git/{repository}/commit/{commitId}

If I inspect the network traffic I see a POST call to:

http://{instance}/{collection}/{projectId}/_api/_versioncontrol/associatedWorkItems?__v=5

Which sends these Body Form Parameters in the request:

- **repositoryId** (GUID) - I already have this
- **versions** - something like
  GC27a36707252ac9db742cc259a1018b9750d8e9a2 (What is this?)
- **__RequestVerificationToken** - API anti-forgery token.

This call returns a list of associated Work Items inside a __wrappedArray collection.

Is there a way to call this from the TFS REST API? If so, where can I get the versions and RequestVerificationToken parameter values?

This is related to my previous question:
[Get latest Associated Work Items for Git Commit using TFS REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46957937/get-latest-associated-work-items-for-git-commit-using-tfs-rest-api)

**Update:** I tried @PatrickLu-MSFT recommendation to pass 'IncludeWorkItems' parameter to `GetcommitsAsync` but still returned WorkItems as null:

```
GitQueryCommitsCriteria crit = new GitQueryCommitsCriteria();
crit.IncludeWorkItems = true;
crit.Ids = new List<string>(){"27a36707252ac9db742cc259a1018b9750d8e9a2"};

var commitTest = gitClient.GetCommitsAsync(repo.Id, crit).Result.FirstOrDefault();
//commitTest.WorkItems == null
```

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT you have helped me in my previous question. Maybe you know more about this one.

Comment: Sorry for the later reply, due to this kind of `@` will not notify me in SO system, you may have to @me at my answer in your original question , if you want to notify me.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, as said before, there is no such kind of Rest API ability to directly show the work items which associated with a GIT commit for now.

Here is also a related uservoice for your reference：

> **Rest API - Ability to show work items associated with a GIT commit**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/5951867-rest-api-ability-to-show-work-items-associated-w

The API you see from network traffic used, maybe a internal way. You could also judge it from the API version, `_v=5` 5 is definitely not a released Rest API version for now.

As a workaround, you could try to use .Net Client to do the similar task.

Specifying `GitQueryCommitsCriteria.IncludeWorkItems = true` in [GitHttpClientBase.GetCommitsAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223313/what-is-the-difference-between-getcommitsasync-and-getcommitsbatchasync) returns associated work items in `GitCommitRef.WorkItems`. Note： both IncludeWorkItems and WorkItems have [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)] which hids it from editor suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @PatrickLu-MSFT. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. I updated my original post with the way I called the `GetCommitsAsync`. Do you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: @AdolfoPerez  GitCommitRef only have includeLinks members https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/versioncontrol/contracts/gitquerycommitscriteria for TFS REST API. And GitCommitRef also only have links for now https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/versioncontrol/contracts/gitquerycommitscriteria  You could try with links ,but should not be the same thing like work item as I think. Which version of TFS are you using?   Seems this only work with VSTS for now.

Answer (score 2):

At least in TFS 2018.2 you can actually do it with [GetCommits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20changes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0), though you should set commitIds through the `ItemVersion`/`FromCommitId`(`GitQueryCommitsCriteria.Ids` won't work):

```
var wiIds = (await git
    .GetCommitsAsync(
        project,
        repository,
        new GitQueryCommitsCriteria
        {
            // Ids query disregards IncludeWorkItems parameter.
            // ItemVersion query seems to disregard the Top parameter and returns 100 commits instead at least in TFS 2018.2.
            // So we use From+To query.
            FromCommitId = commitId,
            ToCommitId = commitId,
            IncludeWorkItems = true,
            Top = 1
        }))
    .Single()
    .WorkItems()
    .Select(wiRef => 
        Int32.Parse(wiRef.Id))
```